# The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler dependency was found

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-hilt

I'm getting the error "The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no `com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler` dependency was found." while building the project.

Here's how I'm adding hilt to my project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I guess you re missing this dependency

`kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"`

*First add the plugin

`apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'`

*Secondly add the dependencies

```
// Dagger Core
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.37"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.37"

// Dagger Android
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.37'
api 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.37'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.37'

// Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
```

*Thirdly add the classpath

`classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha"`

PS : if you re using java replace kapt with annotationProcessor

Comment: I added the dependency that you told with `androidProcessors` as I'm using Java but after that I got Gradle DSL method not found: androidProcessors(). So replacing the `androidProcessors` with `annotationProcessor` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: my bad yeah i was supposed to say annotationProcessor , sorry for that and im glad that it worked for you mate , good luck

Comment: Is Dagger core and Dagger Android really required while implementing Hilt?

Comment: is classpath needed? not mentioned in official docs

Answer (score 22):

My issue was that I used incorrect dependency syntax when tried adding Hilt dependency to the root `build.gradle` in the project using new Gradle syntax `id 'pluginId' version 'pluginVersion»' [apply false]`

Instead of

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ....
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
    }
}
```

I used

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.41' apply false
}
```

Comment: Additionally, For defining common dependencies like we used to do with global extensions, we just need to define them in gradle.properties and they could easily be shared between project and module.

Comment: Really, but the documentation states to add classpath :S

Answer (score 20):

In case you are using this compiler dependency:

```
"com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Just change it to:

```
"com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Comment: Yup, this solve my error. The docs at https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?authuser=1#setup , didn't say add "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version" dependency.

Answer (score 11):

Keep as it is,

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` or

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

This will fix your issue

Comment: Note: This has not been working for me in 2024. I've had to use `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.9.22" apply false` instead.

Answer (score 10):

### build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
    }
}
```

No matter how much we apply the plugin, if the following dependencies are not applied, the error is obtained

### build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
}
```

Comment: After adding dependencies, the issue disappeared

Answer (score 5):

If you are using **version catalog** and **ksp**
in *libs.version.toml(version catalog)*

```
[versions]
agp = "8.2.2"
kotlin = "1.9.21"
ksp-version = "1.9.22-1.0.17"
hilt-version = "2.44"

[libraries]
.....
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt-version" }
hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt-version" }

[plugins]
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp-version" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt-version" }
```

and in build.*gradle.kts(project)*

```
plugins {
....
 alias(libs.plugins.ksp) apply false
 alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
}
```

and in *build.gradle.kts(Module:app)*

```
plugins {
...
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
}

android{
....
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
.....
  implementation(libs.hilt.android)
  ksp(libs.hilt.compiler)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In some scenarios I have encountered, I have a running project in one of my workstations, but when I checkout in another machine, it brings this issue.

It's because the hilt android plugin is applied, but fetching the dependencies has not yet reached the section to download the compiler dependency.

A simple fix is to comment out the `id(BuildPlugins.hiltPlugin)` if you are using `plugins{}` or `apply plugin BuildPlugins.hiltPlugin`, try to sync again, then once you have a successful build(with hilt issues - but the required dependency has been downloaded), you can un-comment the line and sync.

Note:BuildPlugins in this case is an object that holds my plugins definitions.

Comment: thank you for answering :) mine is id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")

Answer (score 4):

be sure to use the following plugin in the **app** module:

```
id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
```

instead of

```
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
```

which is wrongufully specified in the official docs (as 2023)

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by adding the following dependencies

```
// Dagger & Hilt
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.40")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.0.0")
kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you added this:

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
```

but your forgot to add the dependencies of hilt into your module

Answer (score 1):

everybody! I met this question today, if you have added all the right plugins and dependencies, and you still get an error, ok——it is a bug in Hilt gradle plugin, not your fault, just comment your implementation of Hilt and rebuild your project and uncomment your implementation after build successfully!

Answer (score 1):

16/sep/2023
Project level build gradle

```
    plugins {
        id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
        id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    }
```

module level build gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}
```

dependency

```
  implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
```

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of times to fix this thing. Finally found a solution which worked for me . [Posted on 2 jan 2024 ]

in the project level buildgradle.kts add this

```
id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
```

Now go back to the app , buildgradle.kts. Add this in Plugins

```
id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
```

In the same page, Scroll down to the Dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:3.10.1")
//Rest of your code
```