# Android Studio : Cause: dagger/hilt/android/plugin/HiltGradlePlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error while opening a project

Cause: dagger/hilt/android/plugin/HiltGradlePlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

What i tried are :

[Plugin [id: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'] was not found in any of the following sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69511275/plugin-id-dagger-hilt-android-plugin-was-not-found-in-any-of-the-following)

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3495

[Dagger-hilt error while compiling project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73061190/dagger-hilt-error-while-compiling-project)

[Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment)

[How to resovle Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600315/how-to-resovle-java-runtime-class-file-version-55-0-this-version-of-the-java)

[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError while integrating firebase performance library in react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264871/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-while-integrating-firebase-performance-li)

[java.lang.unsupportedclassversionerror in gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041148/java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-in-gradle-build)

[The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler dependency was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62882730/the-hilt-android-gradle-plugin-is-applied-but-no-com-google-daggerhilt-android)

Comment: I am also facing exactly this same error today. Kindly let me know if you found the solution.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h2jdDdmU3Y

Comment: you already visited the link but sorry to hear that your problem is not solved yet

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h2jdDdmU3Y) solution reported fixed the issue in my case, however here the instructions for the very latest Android Studio version (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1) on MacOS

1. Select your project App main folder in the Android Studio Project panel
2. Right click -> Open Module Settings
3. Select the Project entry below the Project Settings section
4. In the drop-down menu next to SDK, select the Java 11 version
5. Click on Apply and OK
6. Rebuild the project

If this doesn't work could be something deeper messed up in your machine JDK configuration or IDE configuration, would be easier I think to uninstall completely the IDE, clean the configuration file and install from scratch. It could be overkill but sometime this is the most reliable way especially when nothing works.

Comment: The YouTube link helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In Android studio (Electric Eel), doing the following might resolve this issue:

**File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Development -> Build Tools -> Gradle** and change the **Gradle JDK** to 11

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above worked for you. Try this:

Click on
**File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location**

Select the right JDK location and sync.

Note: If you are using latest Android Studio you might not see the last part ***JDK Location*** but ***JDK Location was moved to Gradle Settings*** instead, click on it and change your JDK location.